# React - Navbar not showing and I am getting a Blank Screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am trying to create a Navbar on a clean React app (with React-Router-Dom) and for some reason I am just getting a blank screen, as far as I can see and from looking up various guides, it should be fine:

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";

function App() {
  return (

  <Navbar/>
   
  );
}

export default App;
```

Index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  
    
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Navbar.js

```
import React from "react";
import {  Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = ()=>{
    return(
        <nav className = "nav-wrapper">
            <div className="container">
                <Link to="/" className="brand-logo">Potter Books</Link>

                <ul className="right">
                    <li><Link to="/">Shop</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/">Cart</Link></li>
                </ul>
            </div>


        </nav>

    );
}


export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to fix that.
What I mostly like to use `BrowserRouter`  into the `App.js`

modify your app.js file by importing `BrowserRouter`

```
import {
  BrowserRouter,
} from "react-router-dom";
```

And then add this in the App function.

```
function App() {
  return (
   <BrowserRouter> 
      <Navbar/>
   <BrowserRouter/>
  );
}

export default App;
```

For more information, you can consult [this page](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter) as well.

Comment: Can you add more information to what the issue is in the OP's code and what your code is doing?

Answer (score 0):

So to fix this you need to add

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";
```

into Index.js

Comment: Answers like this do not really add any value to the Stackoverflow community. Please consider updating your answer to add some explanation to your code. Welcome to StackOverflow!